# Can I tell Javascript to call a method from another JS file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function-calls

In AppMenu.js,

```
AppMenu = function()
{
   var scope = this;
}
```

Also noted:

```
Star.Bus.addEvent("AppMenu_StatSheet");
Star.Bus.on("AppMenu_StatSheet", scope.AppMenu_StatSheet, scope);
scope.registerApp("Exit Game", "AppMenu/images/exit_button.png", "AppMenu_exit", "");
```

---

Further down is a method

```
scope.AppMenu_StatSheet = function()
{
    showStats();
}
```

I moved the location of the `showStats()` method to another js file, and I want the method to send its call there instead of where it originally was going. In Javascript, can I tell the program where to look to call `showStats()`?

**EDIT** Curiously, there is no AppMenu.html. I now believe that all of the html is dealt with by a main HTML file in the above folder.

Comment: As long as the file with the function you are calling is included before you try to access it you will be fine. At least if it is in the same scope

Comment: This sounds like a server-technology-specific question.  What stack are you using?  Is this really a .NET dependency loading question in disguise?

Comment: @jimbojw Eheh... I'm not for sure. I'm still a newbie at programming. It very well may be. And I do not know what "stack" I am using.

Comment: stack means "set of technologies".  For example, if your server is a Linux machine running Apache with PHP and a MySQL database, you have a LAMP stack.  If you're running IIS with ASP.NET/C# connecting to SqlServer 2008, you have a Microsoft stack.  If you deploy a WAR file to JBOSS, then you have a J2EE stack, etc etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you include both Javascript files in your PHP/HTML page, the compiler automatically uses your showStats() function, even when it is called from file1.js and the actual function is located in file2.js.

Comment: The problem is is that there is no AppMenu.html

Comment: Was able to figure out that I needed to check something in the HTML (even if it isn't AppMenu's specifically) from your answer

Answer (score 1):

As long as you include both files in your HTML page you'll be fine. Maybe load the file with showStats() before the other one.